# Deformed Cloth Simulation

Tags: cloth-simulation

[image]
[image]

Hi, When I do the cloth simulation for this tshirt, there's a fold in the shoulder area. I've tried smoothing it out in sculpt mode however it doesn't remove it and I've tried playing around with physics settings i.e 'self collision settings' however it still remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. check the normals and recalculate..
2. check and revome double vertices...
3. add more steps to the simulation for example 10 for quality and 5 for collisions...
4. check that you did properly the stitches in the mesh...
5. make sure your cloth is big enough to fit the character, but first try tweaking first some settings in the cloth setting physics settings...